# javascript adding value to an json object in a loop

Tags: javascript, json

I'm adding a value to each object in the object list. But I don't know why its adding the date for every object in every loop.

this is my code:

```
var emptyday: {
    "date":""
}

//make list of days in month
var monthlist = [];
for (i=0;i<=days_in_months;i++) {
    monthlist[i] = emptyday;
}
```

So in my example lets say that days_in_months is 31 (days)

Now comes the adding

```
for (x=1;x<=days_in_months;x++) {

    console.log(x);
    if (x<10) {
        daynumber = "0" + x;
    } else {
        daynumber = x;
    }

    datestring = year + "-"+ (month+1) + "-" + daynumber;

    dayofmonth = monthlist[x]; 
    dayofmonth["date"] = datestring;
            //monthlist[x].date = datestring;

}
```

When I try adding (dayofmonth["date"] = datestring or monthlist[x].date) it adds to all date values of all objects in every loop.

The console.log looks like this for the first loop:

[Object { date= "2013-1-01"}, Object { date= "2013-1-01"}, Object { date= "2013-1-01"}, Object { date= "2013-1-01"}, Object { date= "2013-1-01"}, Object { date= "2013-1-01"}, etc

for 31 times in the first loop

And in the last loop it will be 2013-1-31

I don't understand why it is adding that value to all objects. I have tried console.log and debugging all over the place to read out values and trying to understand what goes wrong, but still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The references in your array all point to the same object.  Javascript is pass by value. So when you do

```
//make list of days in month
var monthlist = [];
for (i=0;i<=days_in_months;i++) {
    monthlist[i] = emptyday;
}
```

the you are putting a **copy of the reference `emptyday` at every position in the array**.  Since the copies of the reference all point to the same object literal, you have an array of references to one object.

You need to create a new object literal every time thru the list.

```
var monthlist = [];
for (i=0;i<=days_in_months;i++) {
    monthlist[i] = {
       date: ""
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks! I was breaking my head with this! big "aha" moment here!

Comment: yay!.  Understanding pass by value semantics will definitely help you going forward, and in other languages too -- when things in some sort of collection change that you don't expect, it's a likely culprit (although not necessarily the only culprit).

Comment: when you said the word "reference", everything was clicking in my mind.thanks! :)